# How to select full month calendar with attendance condition in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Good day! I tried searching this problem all over stack overflow but I cant find the right keyword to search, I guess its better to ask you guys for help.

I am trying to create an attendance history that is base on two tables:

1. attendance table
2. calendar_dimension table

attendance table has data like below

```
|  idnumber   |   punchin   |   punhout   |  date_created  |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|   0002      |    7:30:00  |   16:00:00  |   2021-11-27   |
|   0003      |    7:30:00  |   16:00:00  |   2021-11-27   |
|   0004      |    7:30:00  |   16:00:00  |   2021-11-27   |


|   0002      |    7:30:00  |   16:00:00  |   2021-11-28   |
|   0003      |    7:30:00  |   16:00:00  |   2021-11-28   |
|   0004      |    7:30:00  |   16:00:00  |   2021-11-28   |

|   0001      |    7:30:00  |   16:00:00  |   2021-11-29   |
|   0002      |    7:30:00  |   16:00:00  |   2021-11-29   |
|   0003      |    7:30:00  |   16:00:00  |   2021-11-29   |
|   0004      |    7:30:00  |   16:00:00  |   2021-11-29   |
```

and calendar_dimension is just a basic table with dates, like so:

Please note that is a full month calendar:

```
|    date     |   datestatus  |
+-------------+---------------+
| 2021-11- 1  to  2021-11-25  |
| 2021-11-26  |   Holiday     |
| 2021-11-27  |               |
| 2021-11-28  |               |
| 2021-11-29  |               |
| 2021-11-30  |               |
```

What I have done so far is by joing calendar_dimension and attendance table.

Now, I have something like this: e.g. for 00001, which is working on my end:

```
|  idnumber   |   punchin   |   punhout   |  date_created  |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|   0001      |    7:30:00  |   16:00:00  |   2021-11-29   |
```

And for 0002:

```
|  idnumber   |   punchin   |   punhout   |  date_created  |   Status   |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+------------+
|   0001      |    7:30:00  |   16:00:00  |   2021-11-27   |  Present   |
|   0001      |    7:30:00  |   16:00:00  |   2021-11-28   |  Present   |
|   0001      |    7:30:00  |   16:00:00  |   2021-11-29   |  Present   |
```

I want my history table looks like this by employee:

```
|  idnumber   |   punchin   |   punhout   |  date_created  |   Status   |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+------------+
|                      2021-11-1 to 2021-11-25                          |
|   0001      |    7:30:00  |   16:00:00  |   2021-11-26   |  Holiday   |
|   0001      |    7:30:00  |   16:00:00  |   2021-11-27   |  Absent    |
|   0001      |    7:30:00  |   16:00:00  |   2021-11-28   |  Absent    |
|   0001      |    7:30:00  |   16:00:00  |   2021-11-29   |  Present   |
```

the 30th of November will be displayed tomorrow.

is there other way to make this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to compute the `status` column, correct?

Something along the lines of `IF(datestatus = 'Holiday', 'Holiday', IFNULL(punchin, 'Absent', 'Present')) AS status` should work, albeit it is a little inelegant.

You'll have to ensure you're not doing an inner join to get a row where there is no attendance for that id, ie, `calendar_dimension c LEFT JOIN attendance a ON ...`

Comment: I tried left join with on c.date = a.date_created still give me the same result.

Comment: Try on c.date = a.date_created AND a.idnumber = '0001'

Comment: wow. its working thanks

Comment: Glad it helped!